# Rsync: Mirror only certain directories based on presence of dotfile

Tags: linux, macos, sync, rsync

I have a large amount of files on a server and I have a partial mirror of these files on my Mac (i.e. only some folders exist in the mirror). I would like to have a sync from the Mac to server using rsync and obviously do not choose the `/mirror` option as that would delete files that I haven't chosen to duplicate on the Mac.

However, there are some directories where I would like this mirror behaviour - for example I have git repositories that need to be mirrored rather than just having files updated.

Is there anyway I can set up a sync process that allows me to apply the mirror behaviour only to certain directories?

Ideally I'd like to be able to create a dotfile, e.g. `.sync-mirror`, place this in a directory and then have this and all directories beneath it mirrored rather than simply having new/updated files copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a file for flagging, you could add those directories you want to be mirrored instead of archived to a textfile, and then do 2 rsync-runs. The mirror-run with this file as include-list, the archive-run with this file as exclude-list.

```
rsync [your options for mirroring] --include-from=/path/to/dirlist [source] [target]
rsync [your options for archiving] --exclude-from=/path/to/dirlist [source] [target]
```

Comment: Nice idea. I can probably use some combination of `find` as well if I want to use the dotfiles.